# Use http response outside?

Tags: angularjs, service

I have a problem when trying to call a variable outside a function

This is the service

```
app.factory('Service', function($http) {
return {
    agentes: function () {
        return $http.get(base_url +'/api/auth/organization/me/tasks/calendar').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
};});
```

within the controller I call:

```
loadAgents();
        function  loadAgents() {
             Service.agentes()
             .then(function(agentes){                        
                    $scope.agentes = agentes.data.trackables;                 
                }); 

        }
```

within the above function I can use $scope.agentes but not outside it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand exactly what is your problem but you have some "mistakes" in your code.You should do

```
app.factory('Service', function($http) {
    return {
        agentes: function () {
            return $http.get(base_url +'/api/auth/organization/me/tasks/calendar');
        }
    }
});
```

Then inside your controller

```
app.controller('myController', ['Service', function(Service) {
    function  loadAgents() {
                 Service.agentes()
                 .then(function(agentes){                        
                        $scope.agentes = agentes.data.trackables;                 
                    }); 

            }

}])
```